Create React App & Jest, unable to make API calls in test files
I made a simple create-react-app, and just trying to call an API in the test case. The api call is actually made, but nothing will be run in the .then function.
The reason I'm trying to figure this out, is because I am using MSW to mock request at network level in another app, and this behavior allowed me no way to test my app. MSW would return the mocked response, but since nothing in the .then() is run, I wouldn't be able to update the states
//App.test.tsx
test("renders learn react link", () => {
  render(<App />);
});


//App.tsx
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        //nothing is not logged in the test terminal
        //so I cannot do setState or something similar
        console.log("data", data);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      app
    </div>
  );
}


The jsdom browser is not a complete browser, it does not understand what is fetch function, so we need to create a global function which behaves similar to fetch and provide a similar mock data(MOCK_DATA) to it.
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
 Promise.resolve({
 json: () => Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA),
 })
);


In CRA the fetch function should have been polyfilled, when I console.log(fetch(url)) it says "Promise {  }", the issue is that in the .then nothing happens
